# How to correctly restore a OOP tensorflow model?

Tags: python, oop, tensorflow

For the sake of a current project, I decided to define a tensorflow model within a class instance. This all worked well until I wanted to restore it to continue training from the latest checkpoint. It is a simple linear regression model which is built upon initialization of the instance. It tries to approximate the function `f(x) = 3x + 1`.

The logic is: if there's no checkpoint yet, create a new model, train it for 20 epochs, save it. If there is already a checkpoint, load it, and continue training from it for 20 epochs.

Now, initially training the network works. But when trying to train it after loading it, it throws the following error:

> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/home/abc/tf_tests/restore_test/restoretest.py', wdir='/home/sku/tf_tests/restore_test')
>
> File
>   "/home/abc/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "/home/abc/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/home/sku/tf_tests/restore_test/restoretest.py", line 71, in
>   
>       model.run_training_step(sess, x, y)
>
> NameError: name 'model' is not defined

The question is: how do restore it and proceed the training properly? I have found an interesting article about OOP [here](https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/), but it does not deal with saving and restoring models.

My code is below. Thank you for helping me out!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class LinearModel(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.build_model()

    def build_model(self):
        # x is input, y is output
        self.x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='x')
        self.y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='y')

        self.w = tf.Variable(0.0, name='w')
        self.b = tf.Variable(0.0, name='b')

        self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step', dtype=tf.int32)

        self.y_pred = self.w * self.x + self.b

        # quadratic error as loss
        self.loss = tf.square(self.y - self.y_pred)

        self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(self.loss)
        self.increment_global_step_op = tf.assign(self.global_step, self.global_step+1)

        return 

    # run a single (x, y) pair through the graph
    def run_training_step(self, sess, x, y):
        _, loss = sess.run([self.train_op, self.loss], feed_dict={self.x:x, self.y:y})
        return loss

    # convenience function for checking the values
    def get_vars(self, sess):
        return sess.run([self.w, self.b])


tf.reset_default_graph()

# training data generation, is a linear function of 3x+1 + noise
tr_input = np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0)
tr_output = 3*tr_input+1+np.random.randn(tr_input.shape[0])


with tf.Session() as sess:

    # check if there are checkpoints
    latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./model_saves')

    # ADDED BY EDIT1
    model = LinearModel()

    # if there are, load them
    if latest_checkpoint:

        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model_saves/lin_model-20.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, latest_checkpoint)  

    # if not, create a new model
    else:

        ### REMOVED BY EDIT1
        ### model = LinearModel()
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        saver = tf.train.Saver()

    # show vars before doing the training
    w, b = model.get_vars(sess)       
    print("final weight: {}".format(w))
    print("final bias: {}".format(b))

    # train for 20 epochs and save it
    for epoch in range(20):
        for x, y in zip(tr_input, tr_output):
            model.run_training_step(sess, x, y)
        sess.run(model.increment_global_step_op)

    saver.save(sess, './model_saves/lin_model', global_step=model.global_step)       

    # show vars after doing the training
    w_opt, b_opt = model.get_vars(sess)       
    print("final weight: {}".format(w_opt))
    print("final bias: {}".format(b_opt))
```

**EDIT1:**

When instantiating the model before checking whether there is an checkpoint or not, it results in an precondition error of an optimizer variable:

> FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value
>   beta1_power    [[Node: beta1_power/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT,
>   _class=["loc:@Adam/Assign"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]]    [[Node: Square/_25 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_103_Square",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't instantiate your LinearModel class when you tried to restore from the checkpoint. This should work:

```
...
latest_checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/home/sku/tf_tests/restore_test/model_saves')

model = LinearModel()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

if latest_checkpoint:
    saver.restore(sess, latest_checkpoint)
else:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it resulted in a `FailedPreconditionError` of an optimizer variable. I will edit the error into my question.

Comment: Did you change your optimizer at any point ? I modified my answer to fit your new error.

Comment: No I did not. If I try it with your modified answer, the training start always from scratch, e.g. the w and b variables have the value zero. But the error is gone!

Comment: I modified my answer once again. The problem was that you imported the graph once again when you used import_meta_graph. You don't need this line since you already defined the graph inside your build_model function.

Comment: That fixed it and makes perfectly sense now. Maybe this is a topic for a feature request, so that you get a warning when doing this.